# MSAL: Acquire token silently in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I need to get silently token. When current token expire time 2 min left that time I called renewToken function, msalService.acquireTokenSilent using I get the token but this token is current token not new token.I am using msal v1. I don't know where is my mistake

```
renewToken(){
const renewIdTokenRequest = {
      scopes: [CLIENTID]
    };
this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(renewIdTokenRequest).then(re=>{
      console.log('response',re)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[From this link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/token-lifetimes.md#token-renewal), it sounds like you only get a new one when the current one has expired.

**Token Renewal**

The PublicClientApplication object exposes an API called acquireTokenSilent which is meant to retrieve non-expired token silently. It does this in a few steps:

1. Check if a token already exists in the token cache for the given scopes, client id, authority, and/or homeAccountIdentifier.
2. If a token exists for the given parameters, then ensure we get a single match and check the expiration.
3. **If the access token is not expired, MSAL will return a response with the relevant tokens.**
4. **If the access token is expired but the refresh token is still valid, MSAL will use the given refresh token to retrieve a new set of tokens, and then return a response.**
5. If the refresh token is expired, MSAL will attempt to retrieve an access tokens silently using a hidden iframe. This will use the sid or username in the account's claims object to retrieve a hint about the user's session.